# How to solve $\lim _{x\to \pi/2}\left(\tan x-1\right)\left(1-\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right) =\infty\cdot 0$?

Tags: limits

$\lim _{x\to \pi/2}\left(\tan x-1\right)\left(1-\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right) $ Is there a way to solve this limit without any fancy trigonometric identity?

Comment: Are you sure that $x\to \infty$, or is it $x\to \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: Assuming the above comment, you have a limit in the form $\infty \times 0$. You can use L'Hôpital's rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule in cases like these. (Rewrite the inside so that it is a fraction with the denominator and numerator both tending to either $0$ or $\infty$)

Comment: pi/2 my bad....

Comment: Could you please define a *'**fancy** trigonometric identity'*? For example, is $\cos(2\theta)\equiv \cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta)$ considered one? (One of the answers below uses it)

Answer (score 3):

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
(1-\tan(x))\,(1-\tan(x/2))&=\frac{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\,\frac{\cos(x/2)-\sin(x/2)}{\cos(x/2)}\\\\
&=\underbrace{\frac{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{\cos(x/2)}}_{\to -\sqrt{2}\,\text{as}\,x\to \pi/2}\,\frac{\cos(x/2)-\sin(x/2)}{\cos(x)}\\\\
\end{align}$$

So, the problem boils down to evaluating the limit

$$\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\frac{\cos(x/2)-\sin(x/2)}{\cos(x)}\overbrace{=}^{LHR}\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\frac{-\frac12\sin(x/2)-\frac12\cos(x/2)}{-\sin(x)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

W/O L'Hospital's rule,

$$\displaystyle\left(\tan x-1\right)\left(1-\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right) =\dfrac{\sin x-\cos x}{\cos\dfrac x2}\cdot\dfrac{\cos\dfrac x2-\sin\dfrac x2}{\cos x}$$

Now $\cos \left[ 2\left(\dfrac x2\right) \right] =\cos^2\dfrac x2-\sin^2\dfrac x2$

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming that you can use Taylor series.*

First, let $x=y+\frac \pi 2$ to make $$(\tan (x)-1)\left(1-\tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right) =(\cot (y)+1)\left(\tan \left(\frac{y}{2}+\frac \pi 4 \right)-1\right) $$ Now, using $$\cot(y)=\frac{1}{y}-\frac{y}{3}+O\left(y^3\right)$$ $$\tan \left(\frac{y}{2}+\frac \pi 4 \right)=1+y+\frac{y^2}{2}+O\left(y^3\right)$$ then 
$$A=(\cot (y)+1)\left(\tan \left(\frac{y}{2}+\frac \pi 4 \right)-1\right)=\left(1+\frac{1}{y}-\frac{y}{3}+O\left(y^3\right) \right)\left(y+\frac{y^2}{2}+O\left(y^3\right)\right)$$ Expanding and simplifying $$A=1+\frac{3 y}{2}+O\left(y^2\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Answer (score 0):

Using double angle formula, $$\tan x=\dfrac{2t}{1-t^2}$$ where $t=\tan\dfrac x2$

$$\implies\lim _{x\to \pi/2}\left(\tan x-1\right)\left(1-\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)=\lim_{t\to1}\dfrac{(2t-1+t^2)(1-t)}{1-t^2}$$

As $t\to1,t\ne1\iff t-1\ne0,$ we can cancel out $1-t$ safely from the denominator & the numerator.